# Do all Android devices have a common downloads directory path?

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a Flutter app. I am trying to save a pdf file to the device's downloads directory.

The path looks like this: `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

Can I assume that all Android devices store downloads in this location, or are there exceptions?

Comment: yes , all android devices have download folder on root of internal storage or sd card ...

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to not just hardcode a path. the path_provider package will help you here. https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

It lets you get the directory you are looking for like this:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as pathProvider;

String dir = (await pathProvider.getDownloadsDirectory()).path;
```

It of course also works for iOS and lets you get the path for many different directories.

Comment: This only works on Desktop. In Ios or Android it gives an os error.

Comment: @UmutArpat at least for ApplicationDirectory it works 100%. Have not tried DownloadsDirectory.

Comment: Thank you but i already tried path_provider and download_path_provider packages.They didnt helped me much.